# Tailwind CSS build error | Acorn unexpected token 26:33

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, tailwind-css, acorn

I tried to build tailwindcss on default css but this thing appears....

```
   tailwindcss 2.0.2

   ? Building from default CSS... (No input file provided)

   ? SyntaxError: Unexpected token (26:33)
    at _class.pp$4.raise (C:\xampp\htdocs\www\css\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.
js:2927:15)
    at _class.pp.unexpected (C:\xampp\htdocs\www\css\node_modules\acorn\dist\aco
rn.js:698:10)
    at _class.pp.expect (C:\xampp\htdocs\www\css\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.j
s:692:28)
    at _class.pp$3.parseObj (C:\xampp\htdocs\www\css\node_modules\acorn\dist\aco
rn.js:2563:14)
    at _class.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\xampp\htdocs\www\css\node_modules\acorn\dis
t\acorn.js:2302:19)
    at _class.parseExprAtom (C:\xampp\htdocs\www\css\node_modules\acorn-node\lib
\dynamic-import\index.js:77:117)
    at _class.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\xampp\htdocs\www\css\node_modules\aco
rn\dist\acorn.js:2129:21)
    at _class.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\xampp\htdocs\www\css\node_modules\acorn\d
ist\acorn.js:2106:19)
    at _class.parseMaybeUnary (C:\xampp\htdocs\www\css\node_modules\acorn-node\l
ib\private-class-elements\index.js:122:54)
    at _class.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\xampp\htdocs\www\css\node_modules\acorn\dist
\acorn.js:2041:21)
```

I tried reinstalling it but nothing changed... how do i fix this?

Comment: Hi there! Can you show us what's on line 26?

Answer (score 7):

After wasting a couple of days, I found that there was a simple typo in my `tailwind.config.js`

```
    '224': '56rem',
    '256': '64rem'.
    '304': '76rem',
```

I suggest checking the line 26 within your own config.

Good luck!

Comment: oh yeah i totally forgot about that... good thing i fixed it already...

Comment: I was missing a bloody comma!